# lightning-cli list only my channels

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, ln-topology

After connecting to a busy lighnting node such as `03c856d2dbec7454c48f311031f06bb99e3ca1ab15a9b9b35de14e139aa663b463@testnet-lnd.htlc.me` the number of channels my own lightning node knows about becomes very large.

Is there a way to get the **lightning-cli listchannels** command to apply a filter and list only the channels my node is directly participating in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `listpeers`. That will only show your direct peers and the channels you have open with them.